# HTML Web Forms - Why is my JavaScript validation wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn html and JavaScript and have produced a webform. All was working well until I tried to add an if statement to validate that only an input of 4 characters is to be accepted and return true to the webform. Removal of the if allows the code to work again...what is wrong with my if? what am I missing?

Any help would be gratefully received.

```
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm()
{
    var result = true;
    var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter your exam number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
        document.getElementById('examno').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEnrty.getElementById("examno").value.length != 4)
        {
        msg+="The exam number must equal 4 \n";
        document.Examentry.examno.focus();
        document.getElementById('examno').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if(msg=="")
        {
        return result;
        }
    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
    }
}

</script>



</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">

<table width="50%" border="0">

<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="examno">examno</td>
<td><input type="number" name="examno" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
```

EDIT:

OK, typo has been corrected and

```
if (document.ExamEnrty.getElementById("examno").value.length != 4)
```

has been changed to

```
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length != 4)
```

but code when run is now returning true to the webform when I add characters of length smaller or longer than 4 when it should return false and throw up an error

code now reads:

```
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm()
{
    var result = true;
    var msg="";

    if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value=="")
        {
        msg+="You must enter your exam number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
        document.getElementById('examno').style.color="red";
        result = false;
        }
    if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length != 4)
            {
            msg+="The exam number must equal 4 \n";
            document.Examentry.examno.focus();
            document.getElementById('examno').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }
    if(msg=="")
        {
        return result;
        }
    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
    }
}

</script>



</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>

<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">

<table width="50%" border="0">

<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="examno">examno</td>
<td><input type="number" name="examno" /></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

</form>
</body>
```

Am I being really stupid?!! HELP

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your code? In the next to last if, the element name is misspelled. `ExamEnrty`

Comment: Typo. `document.ExamEnrty.getElementById("examno").value.length`. should be ExamEntry.

Comment: *Read* the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues with your if statement, and two of them are typos. First you misspelled `ExamEnrty` in the line:

```
if (document.ExamEnrty.getElementById("examno").value.length != 4)
```

That should be:

```
if (document.ExamEntry.getElementById("examno").value.length != 4)
```

But that's not even the answer because that will refer to the element with the ID of `examno` which is the table cell parent of the input you want. Instead, replace that line with:

```
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length != 4) {
```

Next you have a typo in the if block on the line:

```
document.Examentry.examno.focus();
```

That should be:

```
document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
```

Fixed **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pf6vL/)**

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Massive help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/chace/YEQf3/32/

```
function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg = "";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value == "") {
    msg += "You must enter your name<br />";
    document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
    document.getElementById('name').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('name').style.color = "black";
}        
if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value == "") {
    msg += "You must enter the subject<br />";
    document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
    document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('subject').style.color = "black";
}    
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value == "") {
    msg += "You must enter your exam number<br />";
    document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
    document.getElementById('examno').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('examno').style.color = "black";
}    
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length != 4) {
    msg += "The exam number must equal 4<br />";
    document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
    document.getElementById('examno').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('examno').style.color = "black";
}    
if (msg == "") {
    document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = "Success!";
    return result;
} else {
    document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerHTML = msg;
    return result;
}
}
```

Also, you should set the red text back to black if it passes the test after the first try, I added that to the fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

You referenced by ID instead of the name of the text field you are trying to validate.

```
if (document.ExamEnrty.getElementById("examno").value.length != 4)
```

should actually be something like

```
if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value.length != 4)
```

sorry, I didn't test the rest of the syntax but the id examno is assigned to your td not your text field

Comment: @samwickins32 - no worries, not sure why someone decided to vote the answer down but I am glad you got it resolved. I hit submit without realizing the first answer had posted, why not just leave it alone since it is a dupe...LOL...